# Simple Query, Huge tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

- Products ( 53k rows )
- Product Categories ( 170k rows )

I'm trying to find uncategorized products with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `jp_harley_products` 
WHERE product_id NOT IN
      (SELECT p_cat_product_id 
FROM jp_harley_product_cats )
```

also tried this:

```
SELECT p.product_id,pc.p_cat_product_id
FROM `jp_harley_products` p 
LEFT JOIN `jp_harley_product_cats` pc on pc.p_cat_product_id = p.product_id
```

My PHPmyAdmin can't handle this, as it doesn't show any results.
In harley_product_cats I have columns like: **Product ID, Cat ID**, so basically I want to get these products which doesn't have any relation in **harley_product_cats**

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a `IS NULL` for the `LEFT JOIN` one to work.

```
SELECT p.product_id, pc.p_cat_product_id
FROM `jp_harley_products` p 
LEFT JOIN `jp_harley_product_cats` pc on pc.p_cat_product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.product_id IS NULL
```

Or try using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT p.product_id, pc.p_cat_product_id
FROM `jp_harley_products` p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM jp_harley_product_cats pc WHERE p.product_id = pc.p_cat_product_id );
```